# Is N<sup>2</sup>-1 solution using A* search that much memory expensive if N is about 10?

Tags: algorithm, memory, a-star, tile

I read somewhere on internet that A* search to solve N<sup>2</sup>-1 consumes too much memory if N is more than 4 or 5. Is it really? Why should we store every state as a matrix rather than the transformation made to reach the current state from its previous state? Isn't it enough to store in each node, the heuristic value and the transformation applied to previous state to reach in current state?

Comment: "I read somewhere on internet" - links?

Comment: Yes A*-search may need exponential memory (related to depth of the search)(see wikipedia: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Complexity] ) but with a good heuristic it is not that bad.

Comment: @MitchWheat It says: "Even with 16!/2 remaining configurations that can be solved, there are still far more states than can be stored in memory in a computer." at http://www.aitopics.org/topic/15-puzzle